# Get error thrown by command-line execution using subprocess python

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess, exit-code

I am trying to retrive error(exit code importantly) thrown by any command line execution in python script itself. I am using subprocess for this. When I execute any wrong commands then it throws an error in terminal as usual, but then it stops executing python file and I can't get store error.

Look at the code. p_status is supposed to store exit code. But before printing it stops the script after throwing error in terminal.

```
process = subprocess.Popen([<command>], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.communicate()
p_status = process.wait()
print(p_status)
```

I went through different solutions and tried all of them but couldn't get the required result.

Comment: What do you mean? If you dont want the script to end you have to `except` the error, but I doubt the process is even being created with a false command.

Comment: You should do this in `try-except` block. Where command is not found, you should catch 'OSError` exception

Comment: So basically I will be running different apps using python. If in case that app doesn't exist in the directory so it will throw an error. I want to catch that error and use it. I tried to use `try` and `except` but since no process was created I couldn't get error.

P.S: Sorry If I sound dumb. I am very new to this.

Comment: Thanks @karolch . I believe it's working well. Wasn't aware of OSError.

Answer (score 0):

Got this problem solved using the following code:

```
try:
    subprocess.Popen([<command>], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
except OSError as error:
    print(error.errno) #for exit code
```

P.S - credits @karolch